# launch iPad app in portrait state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

How can I load my app only in portrait state, when shown launch image? My app support all orientations, but I need launch it in portrait state for my launch image

Comment: If it supports all orientations, why not include a landscape launch image? There is a way to set the orientation, but that stops the app from supporting landscape orientation.

Comment: @ThomasW I need it, launch only in portrait state but support all orientations =) I have no time to explain why I need it =)

Comment: Make the landscape images look like the portrait image... just rotate them. There are some better ways, but I don't have the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

//Try this it will work

**//Option 1:**

in .plist file make changes only in row **Supported interface orientations**
[image]

**//Option 2:**

if the above thing is not working try like this

which image you are using for Landscape, edit and save the same image with different name for Portrait and **rotate** that image using your **Preview** from Landscape to Portrait(left to right or right to left).

Comment: I think you too didn't has time to read the question well ;), "My app support all orientations"

Comment: sorry, try Option 2 from above

Answer (score 1):

Add this code In AppDelegate for first launch,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

}
```

> Implementing this method in each view controller :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 

{
           return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation); // whatever you need put here.
}
```